# Regex for no more than 5 digits or contain string

Tags: php, regex

I looking for a regex that returns true if string include characters or only 5 digits or include a string for php

tried this  `^\D{0,5}$`

but it's not working

for examples:

```
12345 - return true
1234455667&&&% . - true

123456 -false 
1234 - true 
FFGF - true 
empty string - true
```

Comment: `1234455667&&&% .` ... this is a match according to your logic, so which characters are allowed?

Comment: $output = preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', $string );

Comment: Did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50037059/3832970) help? If not, please let know via a comment if you need more assistance.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly. You want `true` if any of the following is true:

- contains no more than 5 digits
- empty string
- contains at least non-digit

We can use `|` to separate these three conditions.

```
^(?:\d{0,5}|.*?\D.*)$
```

Note that the empty string case is also matched by `\d{0,5}`

Comment: I think your pattern can be enhanced to `^(?:\d{0,5}|\d*\D.*)$`. The empty alternative is redundant as `\d{0,5}` matches an empty string already and `\d*` will match up to the first non-digit quicker than `.*?`.

Comment: This is by far the shortest answer without using lookaheads. It could be shorter too `^(\d{0,5}|.*\D.*)$`. You have my upvote.

Answer (score 1):

PHP code ([test online](https://3v4l.org/ZQVXb)):

```
$str = '1234';
if (preg_match('~^(?(?=\d+$)\d{1,5}|.*)$~', $str)) {
    // true
}
```

If you are telling digits shouldn't be 5 or more you should build paths for them. One way is using conditional construct which PCRE has a support for `(?()...)`:

```
^(?(?=\d+$)\d{1,5}|.*)$
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/iholhx/2)

Breakdown:

- `^` Match beginning of input string
- `(?` Start of conditional

  - `(?=\d+$)` Positive lookahead, if digits only
  - `\d{1,5}` It should be at most five characters long
  - `|` Otherwise
  - `.*` Match any thing else
- `)` End of construct
- `$` Match end of input string

Answer (score 1):

You may match a string that consists of 1 to 4 digits, or is empty, or is not all digits:

```
if (preg_match('~^(\d{1,5}|(?!\d+$).*)$~', $v)) {
    return true;
}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BjJ0mk/1). Details:

- `^` - start of string
- `(` - start of a grouping construct matching...

  - `\d{1,5}`  - 1 to 5 digits
  - `|` - or
  - `(?!\d+$).*` - any 0+ chars (other than line break chars, add `s` modifier to make it match strings with line breaks) as many as possible, but not equal to all digits
- `)` - end of the grouping construct
- `$` - end of string.

See [PHP demo](http://rextester.com/TIRAW82781):

```
$strs = ['12345', '1234455667&&&% .', '123456', '1234', ''];

foreach ($strs as $v) {
    if (preg_match('~^(\d{1,5}|(?!\d+$).*)$~', $v)) {
        echo "$v: true\n";
    } else {
        echo "$v: false\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
12345: true
1234455667&&&% .: true
123456: false
1234: true
: true
```